Mega Menu cant view more than 7 submenu
I try to create a mega menu with more than 6 submenu (specifically 7 submenus) but when i add it in model it gives an view error like this:
enter image description here
it supposed to be col-1 and width: 8.3333%; in Grid System
but when i reduce to 6 it change to this:
enter image description here
it is obvious because in Grid System
